# Android: can I use 800x1280 images on the xhdpi folder?

Tags: android

According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630868/which-size-should-a-background-be-for-ldpi-mdpi-hdpi-and-xhdpi-screens), on "normal" phone screens I should use a 320x480 background image for mdpi, 480x800 for hdpi and 640x960 for xhdpi.

However I am having some troubles to get the scale of my images right on the Galaxy S3, Galaxy Note and Galaxy Nexus, all of which have a resolution of 800x1280 (720x1280 in the S3 and Nexus cases). Most of the time my 640px wide background will get stretched to 720 or 800, but other images won't (as I explained in [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975458/android-os-not-re-sizing-images-with-the-same-scale)).

**One solution seemed to work**: instead of using 640x960 images on the xhdpi folder use 800x1280, as that is the exact resolution of those devices, so pretty much no re-sizing is needed.

However this breaks the 4:6:8 ratio recommended by the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to be maintained between the mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi.

**My question**: would it be OK to use my solution? Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: "According to the Android Developer Guide, on "normal" phone screens I should use a 320x480 background image for mdpi, 480x800 for hdpi and 640x960 for xhdpi" -- the documentation does not say that, at least not on the page that you linked to. For example, "960" appears precisely twice on that page, once in the context of a `dp` value for `-xlarge` screens, once as a "representative resolution" for an `-xhpi`, `-normal` screen. The phrase "background image" appears once, referring to a 9-patch PNG for a button.

Comment: I concluded that by reading the stuff there, but I might be wrong. Anyway I changed my reference to another SO thread where a guy answers with those values. Do you know anything about using 640x960 or 800x1280 images on the xhdpi folder though?

Comment: Neither answer on that question cites those values. The only one that comes close cites density-independent pixels (`dp`), and your question is in units of pixels (`px`) based on your device resolutions. `dp` and `px` are only equivalent on `-mdpi` screens. You can use any image in any folder you want, but do not assume that `-xhdpi` means a certain resolution in pixels, because it is not.

Comment: OK I guess I need to read further to understand this topic. Thanks for your comments.